# Does fseek() move the file pointer to the beginning of the file if it was opened in "a+b" mode?

Tags: c, append, fopen, fseek

I wish to open a file using the "a+b" mode, i.e. if it does not exist it is created automatically, but if it does I don't want to overwrite it. I want to be able to read and write to the file.

The file is binary, and I want to save records of a specific `struct` in it. So I want to do `fseek()` to the record I want and then save the record using `fwrite()`.

The code looks as follows (`MyRecord` is a `typedef` to a `struct`, while `FILENAME` is a `#define` to the file's name):

```
int saveRecord(MyRecord *pRecord, int pos)
{
    FILE* file = fopen(FILENAME, "a+b");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to open file %s\n", FILENAME);
        return 0;
    }

    fseek(file, pos * sizeof(MyRecord), SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(pRecord, sizeof(MyRecord), 1, file);
    fclose(file);
    return 1;
}
```

However this code just appends the record to the end of the file, even if I set `pos` to 0. Why isn't `fseek()` with `SEEK_SET` working in append mode?

I know I can simply open it with "r+b" and if it fails open it with "wb", but I want to know why this doesn't work and why `fseek()` with `SEEK_SET` is leaving the file pointer at the end. Any references to places where this behaviour is documented appreciated (because I couldn't find any, or I am using the wrong keywords).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's because in `a` mode, writing to the `FILE*` always appends to the end. `fseek` only sets the read pointer in this mode. This is documented in the C standard, **7.19.5.3 fopen**:

> Opening a file with append mode (`'a'` as the first character in the mode argument)
>   causes all subsequent writes to the file to be forced to the then current end-of-file,
>   regardless of intervening calls to the `fseek` function.

Answer (score 4):

Use "r+b" mode and fallback to "w+b" if it fails.

The "a+b" mode, allows you to read and append; the "r+b" allows random read and write.

The documentation for [`fopen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html) describes how the file behaves with the different modes.

Comment: This has a race condition that will clobber your file.

Comment: @R..: what race condition? should I say "fallback to "wb" if it fails with `errno == ENOENT`"

Comment: I'm assuming a multitasking OS where another process could create the file and fill it with data after the first `fopen` fails but before the second `fopen` attempt. If OP is dealing with an embedded system or any closed system where it's known that this won't happen, it may be a non-issue.

Comment: I see @R.. thanks. If that's an issue `fwrite` to the same position at the same time by different processes is also an issue; the OP could use the same method to manage both issues.

Answer (score 4):

Plain C does not have any sane way to achieve what you want. If you're on a POSIX system or anything remotely close, you can use `fd=open(FILENAME, O_CREAT|O_RDRW, 0666)` and then `fdopen(fd, "rb+")`.

**Edit:** Another thing you could try, with plain C:

```
f = fopen(FILENAME, "a+b");
if (!f) /* ... */
tmp = freopen(0, "r+b", f);
if (tmp) f = tmp;
else /* ... */
```

Comment: Yes I guess that would work. I need this to work on pure ANSI C though. Still +1 for you for the good alternative.

Comment: Have you tried the `freopen` solution? No idea if it works in practice (`freopen` is ill-specified and could in theory be useless) but it might be ok.