# Write text to the single text file in multiple c files

Tags: c, file

I have defined functions in multiple files. I want to write some text to the same file according to their execution same as below.
I have found the way to write execution flow in different in file as below.

**function1.h**

```
#ifndef FUNCTION1_H_INCLUDED
#define FUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED

int Sum(int a, int b);

#endif
```

**function1.c**

```
#include "function1.h"

int Sum(int a, int b)
{
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("E:\\tmp\\test.txt", "a");
    fputs("Inside Sum function...\n", fp);
    fclose(fp);

    return a+b;
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "function1.h"

int main() {
   int a=10, b=12;
   FILE *fp;

   fp = fopen("E:\\tmp\\test.txt", "a");
   fputs("Before Sum function...\n", fp);
   fclose(fp);

   printf("%d + %d = %d", a, b, Sum(a, b));

   fp = fopen("E:\\tmp\\test.txt", "a");
   fputs("After Sum function...\n", fp);
   fclose(fp);

}
```

Above solution is very difficult to handle when there are more multiple files.
Is there direct way to write *test.txt* in multiple *.c files?

Comment: What do you mean by “very difficult to handle” ? What problem are you trying to resolve exactly ?

Comment: You could open the file in main and pass the file pointer to the function - after changing the signature - rather than hard code the file name in lots of places. I;m not clear what you would mean by multiple files

Comment: I want to check the execution path. This is a simple example for understanding.
If the execution path is working following text should be written the test.txt fiel.

Before Sum function...
Inside Sum function...
After Sum function...

Comment: Multiple file mean main.c and function1.c. I will try this passing file pointer to the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may open a file and pass its descriptor like an argument:

**function1.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#ifndef FUNCTION1_H_INCLUDED
#define FUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED

int Sum(int a, int b, FILE *f);

#endif
```

**function1.c**

```
#include "function1.h"

int Sum(int a, int b, FILE *f)
{
    fputs("Inside Sum function...\n", f);
    return a+b;
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "function1.h"

int main() {
   int a=10, b=12;
   FILE *fp;

   fp = fopen("E:\\tmp\\test.txt", "a");
   fputs("Before Sum function...\n", fp);

   printf("%d + %d = %d", a, b, Sum(a, b, fp));

   fputs("After Sum function...\n", fp);
   fclose(fp);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass file pointer as argument `int Sum(int a, int b, File *F)` then (at the end) you can lseek to SEEK_SET to go back at beginning of file.

Comment: Not in `'a'` mode surely? Why why do you want to rewind?

Comment: you don't need 'a' mode if you pass file as argument (you open it once at beginning of your program)

Comment: I may be muddling `'a'` and `'a+'` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25963995/using-fseek-with-append though I;'m still not sure why you mention `SEEK_SET`

Comment: so you can open your file in `"wb"` or `"wt"`

Comment: Another solution is "close the file after last write" than re-open it again for  last read.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Define SHOW_WHERE to turn on show_where() */
#define SHOW_WHERE

#ifdef SHOW_WHERE

#define show_where(fp) \
    fprintf(fp, "FILE=%s\tLINE=%d\tFUNC=%s\tDATE=%s\tTIME=%s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__,  __DATE__, __TIME__); \
    fflush(fp);

#else

#define show_where(fp)

#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    show_where(stdout);

    return 0;
}
```