# Random access of a file with fseek in C

Tags: c, filesystems

I am trying to write some data in the middle of an existing file, however, it isn't clear what mode to open with. If I open with "w" it'll truncate the file, so "a" seems the obvious choice. What I'd want to do is open with "a" and then seek to the necessary position. However, when I do that it always writes to the end:

```
FILE* t = fopen("ttt", "w");
fprintf(t, "1234567890");
fclose(t);
t = fopen("ttt", "a");
int result = fseek(t, 2, SEEK_SET);
fprintf(stderr, "%d", result);
fprintf(t, "xxx");
fclose(t);
```

I'd expect the test file ttt to contain "12xxx67890" but it contains "1234567890xxx". (Result of fseek is 0.)

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: From [cppreference - fopen, fopen_s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen): *On the append file access modes, data is written to the end of the file regardless of the current position of the file position indicator.*

Comment: Does that mean it cannot be done with FILE, and I have to go to basic open with file descriptors instead?

Comment: I am not that familiar with C file IO but it should work with `"r+"`. Note: *In update mode ('+'), both input and output may be performed, but output cannot be followed by input without an intervening call to fflush, fseek, fsetpos or rewind, and input cannot be followed by output without an intervening call to fseek, fsetpos or rewind, unless the input operation encountered end of file. In update mode, implementations are permitted to use binary mode even when text mode is specified.*

Comment: Have you tried `r+`? That is to open the file for reading and writing (and you do not have to read). You may also want `rb+` depending on the kinds of seeks you are going to do. Without `b`, only seeks to the start, end, or a position obtained with `ftell` may be supported.

Comment: Yes.... "r+" does the job (not bad from the guy who says "I am not that familiar with C file IO" . If you can put it in an answer, I'll accept so that future searches will find it.

Comment: @FraserOrr *I have to go to basic open with file descriptors instead?* You can't on Linux. On POSIX systems, you should be able to `open()` a file with `O_APPEND` and then use `pwrite()` to write to any location, and all writes will be atomic.  [Linux `pwrite()` is broken](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pwrite.2.html#BUGS): "POSIX requires that opening a file with the O_APPEND flag should have no effect on the location at which pwrite() writes data. However, on Linux, if a file is opened with O_APPEND, pwrite() appends data to the end of the file, regardless of the value of offset."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd expect the test file ttt to contain "12xxx67890" but it contains "1234567890xxx". (Result of fseek is 0.)

[`fseek()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek) is not the problem. You can still reposition the pointer with it, but each write in append mode will set it to point to the end of the file.

[cppreference - fopen, fopen_s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen):

> On the append file access modes, data is written to the end of the file regardless of the current position of the file position indicator.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631862/fseek-does-not-work-when-file-is-opened-in-a-append-mode) question on [`fseek()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek) in append mode. This behavior can be useful when using `"a+"` to read from the file as well as writing.

---

To work around this you can use read extended mode `"r+"`. This lets you read and write to the file without you having to close and reopen it.

[cppreference - fopen, fopen_s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen):

> In update mode (`'+'`), both input and output may be performed, but output cannot be followed by input without an intervening call to [`fflush`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush), [`fseek`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek), [`fsetpos`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fsetpos) or [`rewind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/rewind), and input cannot be followed by output without an intervening call to [`fseek`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek), [`fsetpos`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fsetpos) or [`rewind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/rewind), unless the input operation encountered end of file. In update mode, implementations are permitted to use binary mode even when text mode is specified.

A working solution might look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE* t = fopen("ttt", "w");

    fprintf(t, "1234567890");
    fclose(t);

    t = fopen("ttt", "r+");
    int result = fseek(t, 2, SEEK_SET);

    fprintf(stderr, "%d", result);
    fprintf(t, "xxx");

    fclose(t);
    return 0;
}
```

You could now be tempted to just use `"r+"` once at the start of your program since it can be used to perform both write actions you use but note that it will not create a new file if it does not exists yet.

Answer (score 2):

When you open a file in 'append' mode *all writes* take place at the end of the file.

MSVC [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=msvc-170) says:

> When a file is opened by using the `"a"` access type or the `"a+"` access type, all write operations occur at the end of the file. The file pointer can be repositioned by using `fseek` or `rewind`, but is always moved back to the end of the file before any write operation is performed. Therefore, **existing data can't be overwritten**.

To open an existing file for both reading and writing, use the `"r+"` mode.

Comment: Although you *can* `fseek` in a text file, it's not usually a very productive thing to do that and overwrite what's there. It's usually better to rewrite to another file with the necessary changes.

Comment: Also, "Whether a write on a text stream causes the associated file to be truncated beyond that point is implementation-defined" (C23 7.23.3/2).  That's a pretty big gotcha to leave hanging around, even if the implementation you initially write for does what you want in that regard.

Comment: @JohnBollinger that's an interesting snippet of knowledge.