# Updating json file with python

Tags: python, json

I want to update my json file using a python script, however the json in the `.json` file is inside of an array `[]` it looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "test": "2",
    "test1": "1"
  },
  
  {
    "test2": "3",
    "test3": "4"
  }
]
```

So far I've tried:

```py
username = "test"

with open("file.json", "a+") as f:
  json_file = json.load(f)
  json_file[0]['username'] = username
  json.dump(json_file, f)
```

error:

````py
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)```
````

Comment: The value you are trying to change is not in your `.json` you have provided.

Comment: How can I make it make another object inside of the array with `username`

Comment: Ok got you, so you want to add a new value to the json file

Comment: Yes with the values I give it (for e.x `test` and `test1`, both inside a new object inside the array

Comment: I think the problem is with the file mode `a+`.  You're starting at the _end_ of the file, and so `json.load()` has nothing to read.

Comment: How'd I otherwise append to the array and not overwrite everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@JohnGordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/494134/john-gordon) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63045434/updating-json-file-with-python#comment111487743_63045434), the error occurs on the `json_file = json.load(f)` line since the file pointer is at the end of file when the file is opened in `a+` mode. You can see that when we move the file pointer to the beginning of the file, reading is done successful:

```py
import json

username = "test"

with open("file.json", "a+") as f:
    f.seek(0)  # move file pointer to the beginning
    data = json.load(f)
    print(data)
```

But when you use `a+` mode, "[the file pointer is returned to the end of file before every write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15826355/8581025)". So when you write to the file, the json data is appended to the end of file, not updating the whole content of the file. So to update your json file, it is more appropriate to use the code below:

```py
import json

username = "test"

with open("file.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

data[0]['username'] = username

with open("file.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

Comment: How can I make it append a new object inside the array with `{"username": "test"}`, instead of overwriting one that already exists?

Comment: @fiji You can do `data.append({'username': username})` instead of `data[0]['username'] = username`.

Comment: Then I get `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'` when I change it to                    `data[0].append({'username': "test"})` I get `KeyError: 0`

Comment: @fiji Did you use the json file on your original post?

Comment: yes, except for that this one is just an empty array `[]`

Comment: @fiji I think maybe your json file contains an empty dict `{}`, not an empty array `[]`. The error message `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'` shows that the read `data` is a `dict` not a `list`.

Answer (score 1):

Try separating the 2 actions of opening and closing the file. Like this:

```
with open("file.json") as obj:
    json_file = json.load(obj)

data = json_file[0]
data["username"] = "test"

with open("file.json") as obj:
   json.dump(data, obj)
```

Comment: That worked, however how do I make a new obj inside of the array? So everytime the code runs it adds/appends a new obj with `"username": "test"`