# Will fwrite() let you write something past the end of the file size?

Tags: c, gcc

```
FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "ab+");
fseek(f, NUMBER_BIGGER_THAN_FILE_SIZE, SEEK_SET);
fwrite(&someStruct, sizeof someStruct, 1l, f);
```

So if I have something like that, will that allow that to be written? And if not, how can I make that happen?

Comment: check the return value of `fseek` - is it successful?

Comment: @coderredoc yes it's successful.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why don't you use some higher-level abstraction (e.g. [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/)...)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch to learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to write over the end of a file.

However in `a` mode (append mode) `fseek` has no effect on `fwrite`.

This is documented in the C standard, 7.19.5.3 fopen:

> Opening a file with append mode ('a' as the first character in the mode argument) causes all subsequent writes to the file to be forced to the then current end-of-file, regardless of intervening calls to the fseek function.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5532426/2005038

Comment: Are you sure? On Linux it is probably not the case.

Comment: So how could i open the file for reading and writing binary, without deleting it's contents?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes, see for reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/5532426/2005038

Comment: @MauricioMartinez Use `r+b`

Comment: @d3L: that reference should go into your answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can `fwrite` past the end of the file (on most [file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system)). If you can't, the [fwrite](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite)  is failing (and gives a negative result).

Of course, that requires the prior [fseek](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek) call to be successful and changing the written file offset. You need to check that. As [d3L answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48473137/841108), `fseek` may  only change the  offset which won't be used by `fwrite` for an *appended* file.

You may want to [fopen](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) with some other mode. Don't use `a` append mode.

For example, you might have the file `tryappend.c` (it has about 509 bytes) below:

```
// file tryappend.c, copy it to tryappend.c2 before running
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
    const char* filnam = "tryappend.c2";
    FILE *f = fopen(filnam, "a+");
    if (!f) 
       { perror(filnam); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
    if (fseek(f, 1024, SEEK_SET)<0) 
       { perror("fseek"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
    const char str[] = "//// ADDED STUFF\n";
    if (fwrite(str, sizeof(str), 1L, f)<0) 
       { perror ("fwrite"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
    fclose(f);
    printf("changed %s\n", filnam);
    return 0;
}
```

and copy it into `tryappend.c2`  before running your `tryappend` executable. Then you can check with a binary editor or with e.g. `od` on Linux that the `fwrite`-n stuff has been appended at offset 510 (not 1024), and finally your `tryappend.c2` file has only 527 bytes (not something like 1040).

If you insist on direct-accessed files, you could use lower-level [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) such as (on Linux or POSIX) [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html), [lseek(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html), [ftruncate(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ftruncate.2.html), [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), [close(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html), etc... Be aware that for performance reasons you often should use large buffers (so `read` or `write` chunks of several kilobytes at least). BTW, on Linux the C standard library (so `<stdio.h>` routines, including `fread`, `fwrite`, [`fflush`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush), ...) is using such system calls.

You could have files which are not seekable. A good example is on Linux some pseudo files from `/proc` file system (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)) such as `/proc/self/maps`, or [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html)-ed files.

You could **find libraries giving you a slightly higher-level abstraction than direct-accessed files**, e.g. [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) or [gdbm](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/manual/gdbm.html) (and I recommend using these). Of course, you could use some [database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database). Read also about [sparse files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file).

You should define and ***document* precisely your [file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format)** (perhaps using some [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) notation), byte by byte. You probably should care about the [portability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porting) of your file format (think of issues like [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), [data alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment), word size), or provide a way to fill or dump your binary file into some more portable textual format.

Comment: This answer throws a lot of almost-surely bad ideas and obscure features at a question which does not give any indication it's calling for them, and doesn't actually address that the problem is append mode. It also asserts a dubious model of separate read & write offsets which is not how append mode works.